# Scroll automático Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Ao clicar em um dos botões pequena ou grande é exibido o container com os cards (Mix Pequena e Só frutas pequenas). Preciso que ao exibir, a página faça o scroll para baixo já que ao exibir o footer cobre os cards. Criei a função `scrollToEnd` para isso mas nada acontece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<template>
<div class="basket">
    <section class="container has-text-centered">
        <div v-if="errored">
            <h3 class="danger">Pedimos desculpas, não estamos conseguindo recuperar as informações no momento. Por
                favor, tente novamente mais tarde.</h3>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <div v-if="loading">
                <h3>Carregando...</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="columns is-mobile">
                <div class="column collum-btn" v-for="(availableSize, key) in availableSizes"
                     :key="availableSize.id">
                    <div class="box-btn-check" v-if="key % 2 === 0">
                        <a class="button basket-btn"
                           @click="selectBasketSize($event, availableSize.id)">{{
                            availableSize.name }} - R$ {{ formatPrice(availableSize.price) }}</a>
                        <img class="check-icon is-hidden" src="../assets/check.png">
                    </div>
                    <div v-else class="box-btn-check">
                        <a class="button basket-btn" @click="selectBasketSize($event, availableSize.id)">{{
                            availableSize.name }} - R$ {{ formatPrice(availableSize.price) }}</a>
                        <img class="check-icon is-hidden" src="../assets/check.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="container mt-30 section-baskets">
        <div class="columns is-desktop">
            <div class="column is-half is-offset-one-quarter">
                <div class="card card-basket" v-for="basket in baskets" :key="basket.id">
                    <header class="card-header">
                        <p class="card-header-title">{{ basket.name }}</p>
                        <button class="button button btn-details"
                                @click="toggleCardContent()">
                            Ver
                        </button>
                        <button class="button btn-that"
                                @click="$emit('thisBasket', { stage: 'Cesta ' + basket.name + ' escolhida', progress: 100 })">
                            Quero Essa!
                        </button>
                    </header>
                    <div class="card-content" :class="{ 'is-hidden': isHidden }">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="columns is-mobile" v-for="category in basket.categories" :key="category.id">
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img :src="storageUrl + category.image">
                                </div>
                                <div class="column is-two-thirds collumn-text-basket">
                                    <p class="text-options-basket">Escolha {{ category.pivot.quantity }}</p>
                                    <p class="text-options-basket">{{ category.name }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'Basket',
    data() {
        return {
            loading: true,
            errored: false,
            availableSizes: [],
            baskets: [],
            isHidden: true,
            activeIcon: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        storageUrl: function () {
            return process.env.VUE_APP_STORAGE;
        },

        apiUrl: function () {
            return process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API;
        }
    },
    props: {},
    methods: {
        selectBasketSize: function (event, size) {
            this.$emit('stage', {
                stage: 'Antes de selecionar os produtos, escolha um tipo de cesta.',
                progress: 0
            });
            if (event.currentTarget.className === 'button basket-btn' && this.$el.querySelector(".basket-btn-selected") === null) {
                this.getSelectedBaskets(size);
                event.currentTarget.nextSibling.className = 'check-icon';
                event.currentTarget.className = 'button basket-btn-selected';
            } else {
                this.getSelectedBaskets(size);
                this.$el.querySelector(".basket-btn-selected").nextSibling.className = 'check-icon is-hidden';
                this.$el.querySelector(".basket-btn-selected").className = 'button basket-btn';
                event.currentTarget.nextSibling.className = 'check-icon';
                event.currentTarget.className = 'button basket-btn-selected';
            }
        },

        formatPrice(value) {
            let val = (value / 1).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
            return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
        },

        toggleCardContent: function () {
            if (this.isHidden === true) {
                return this.isHidden = false;
            }
            return this.isHidden = true;
        },

        getSelectedBaskets: function (id) {
            axios
                .get(this.apiUrl + '/baskets/' + id + '')
                .then(response => {
                    this.baskets = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errored = true;
                    console.log(error);
                })
                .finally(() => this.loading = false)
            this.scrollToEnd();
        },

        scrollToEnd: function () {
            var container = this.$el.querySelector(".section-baskets");
            container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
            .get(this.apiUrl + '/available-sizes')
            .then(response => {
                this.availableSizes = response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.errored = true;
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(() => this.loading = false)
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.basket {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.danger {
    color: red;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.collum-btn {
    padding: 10px;
}

.basket-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #86cb3c;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #86cb3c;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    &:hover {
        position: absolute;
        top: -10%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #86cb3c;
        color: #86cb3c;
        border: 1px solid #86cb3c;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
}

.basket-btn-selected {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #86cb3c;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    &:hover {
        position: absolute;
        top: -10%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #86cb3c;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
}

.box-btn-check {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.check-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: -32px;
    right: 0;
}

@media(min-width: 992px) {
    .basket-btn {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        color: #629b30;
        border: 1px solid #629b30;
    }

    .basket-btn:hover {
        background-color: #86cb3c;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        border: none;
    }

    .basket-btn-selected {
        background-color: #86cb3c;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #86cb3c;
    }
}

.card-basket {
    margin: 10px 15px 20px 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.card-header {
    p {
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    }
}

.btn-details {
    background-color: #629b30;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 0;
}

.btn-that {
    background-color: #629b30;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
}

.collumn-text-basket {
    padding-top: 16px;
}

.text-options-basket {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso não haja nenhum impedimento para você, aconselho instalar 
o pacote https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scrollto e caso você queira saber como fazer a implementação por conta própria, dê uma lida no código fonte para entender como manipular o evento.

Para resolver o problema usando o pacote, basta instalar e configurar o mesmo dentro do arquivo main.js onde o vue é instanciado.

Feito isso, basta utilizar a diretiva **v-scroll-to="'#idDoElemento'"** dentro do botão ou link que executará a ação de scoll.

Comment: Seria ótimo se colocasse as partes importantes no corpo da resposta, e não somente o link. Aconselho que leia o [tour] para saber mais sobre como funciona o site.